# How to run the Jenkins with different user in Docker Container

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

I am new to Jenkins and making the Jenkins image inside the docker in ubuntu 18.04.

I have some commands in the build step while creating a new Freestyle project. I want to run it with a specific user and not with Jenkins.
At the moment, it is running the commands in the build step by the Jenkins user.

Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Comment: You can add in the Dockerfile a user and start the container with this user (CLI: `-u userName`, docker-compose `user: userName` ) or change later via CLI to this user (`su - userName`)

Comment: Can you add your dockerfile here